# Suspending and resuming threads in c++

Tags: c++, windows, resume, suspend

My application has to suspend and resume a different process every few *microsec*s.
It works fine only sometimes it feels like it suspends the process for non-uniforms times.
I use the win API: `ResumeThread` and `SuspendThread`.

On the other hand, I tried something a little different.
I suspended the thread as usual with `SuspendThread` but when I resume it, I do like so:

```
while (ResumeThread(threadHandle) > 0);
```

and it works faster and it runs the other process in a uniform pace.
Why does it happen? is it possible that sometimes the thread gets suspended twice and then the ResumeThread command executes?
thanks :)

Comment: "yes, it's possible". You need to show more code.

Comment: If you want to do the scheduling yourself, you might want to use fibers instead of threads (e.g., see ConvertThreadToFiber: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682115.aspx).

Comment: I can't, It's really A LOT of code. but theoretically could this be the reason? where can I read about it?

Comment: Windows isn't a realtime OS. You have no guarantees what other threads are running, or how long you will have to wait for those. On my Windows XP there are more than 700 threads active (and the machine is idling :-).

Comment: In three words: "Don't do it!". SuspendThread is a source of hard to track deadlocks. Use proper synchronization (e.g. named semaphore) instead. Have the other process _block_ not _suspended_.

Comment: @Idov:  Please add way more context about the actual endgame objective from a more system perspective.  What you have written suggests there is a major architectural flaw, the least of which is attempting to use Windows for realtime anything.

Comment: Is the target process yours (i. e. written by you or your company, sources available) or third-party? If it's yours, you're Doing It Wrong, please reconsider.

Comment: Please please please don't call SuspendThread.

Comment: Even if thread are "fine grained" parallelism units, a few microseconds should be on the order of the scheduling granularity...

Comment: the target process is not mine. Is there another way besides "SuspendThread" to suspend a process (which I don't have access to its code)?

Comment: @wallyk: It's supposded to be some kind of a small profiler, so I need to sample the target process every X microsecs. I can't sample that process while it's running so I need to suspend it first and then I get the weird problem I described...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SuspendThread()` call does not suspend a thread instantly. It takes several time to save an execution context, so that `ResumeThread()` might be called when a thread has not suspended yet. That's why `while (ResumeThread(threadHandle) > 0);` works. To determine the current thread state you can call [NtQueryInformationThread()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684283%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but only in NT versions of Windows.

If you have a loop in the secondary thread, you can change your synchronization with a Manual Reset Event. The primary thread should call `ResetEvent()` to suspend a thread, and `SetEvent()` to resume. The secondary thread every loop should call `WaitForSingleObjectEx()`.

Comment: so "while (ResumeThread(threadHandle) > 0);" works because "SuspendThread" can get executed twice in a row before "ResumeThread" executes and then the suspend count get too high to be released by just one call to "ResumeThread"?

Comment: I understood that you do paired calls of SuspendThread and ResumeThread. If not - you must call ResumeThread as many times as you called SuspendThread, because each thread has a 'suspend counter'.

Comment: I do call them in pairs, so I do need to use "while (ResumeThread(threadHandle) > 0);"?

Answer (score 0):

I followed Damon's suggestion, removed suspend / resume from the code and instead used a synchronization object over which my pool thread waits infinitely after completing the work and the same is signaled by my server thread after allocating work to it.

The only time I have to use suspend now is when I create the thread for the first time and after allocating work to it the thread is resumed from my server thread. The thread created is used in a thread pool over and over again to do some work.

It is working like a charm.

Thank you Damon!

Regards,

Ajay

Answer (score 0):

thats the way de loop look's like

```
for(i=0;i<num;i++) {     
  while (ResumeThread(threadHandle) > 0);
  ResumeThread(threadHandle)
  SuspendThread(threadHandle);      
}
```

`SuspendThread` takes a few milliseconds so the while loop goes on until thread is suspended, after that, again the thread process `SuspendThread` function is called, a good way to call `GetProcessContext` to see EIP